# a good and latest apache thrift reference

Tags: scala, thrift

I am new to apache thrift. Can someone tell me where I can find a good reference for learning thrift. Some of references i have found were somewhat outdated. it's appreciated if it is in Scala.

Comment: I listed a number of references to various documents and tutorials just a few days ago (ok, not Scala, but does not really matter): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653240/what-is-rpc-framework-and-apache-thrift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tooling available to date for Scala/Thrift servers is Twitter Finagle.

Start here for basic samples:
http://twitter.github.io/finagle/

The bottom of the page goes in slightly more depth.

To get you started, you need:

- SBT build definition
- SBT Scrooge plugin: https://github.com/twitter/sbt-scrooge
- `scrooge-core` + `finagle-thrift` dependency
- There's also a Maven alternative if you prefer Maven
- In your `project/src/main/scala` add a `thrift` folder.

  If it's a multi-project build, simply add `com.twitter.ScroogeSBT.newSettings` to a sub-project's settings.

Now you can start defining models in:
`project/subproject/src/main/thrift/`.

```
namespace java company.firstthrift

struct Test {
   1: required i64 id
}
```