# Articles/discussions/resources on apache thrift

Tags: thrift

I have just come across Apache Thrift, and I was looking for articles that explains some of the following,

What are the advantages of Thrift over Web Services ?

Are there any comparisons of Thrift ?

When is it recommended to use Thrift over existing frameworks like Rest, SOAP or any other technology?

Some of the articles I was able to find are the following,

[Cloud Implementation](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-cloud-apache-thrift/)

[Rest Alternatives](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/12/rest-alternatives)

[Evernote Implementation](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2013/10/03/is-evernotes-restless-api-approach-a-model-for-other-api-designs/)

Comment: `advantages of Thrift over Web Services ` - Maybe it's just a terminology problem, but how would you define "Web Service"? I have implemented Web Services offering both a SOAP and a Thrift API in parallel (in fact, you can even switch between them freely). Additionally, I'd like to point to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653240/what-is-rpc-framework-and-apache-thrift/20664706#20664706, where I listed a number of other helpful sources of information.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the questions on Goals, Comparisons, Performance etc, are answered in the following Slideshare [Thrift vs Protocol vs Avro](http://www.slideshare.net/IgorAnishchenko/pb-vs-thrift-vs-avro).

[Role in Distributed Applications](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/manningpubs/archive/2013/08/01/apache-thrift%E2%80%99s-role-distributed-applications)