# Best way to exchange data between C# and executable JAR

Tags: java, c#, .net, ipc, executable-jar

I'm working with `EXI`, which encodes `XML` into a binary format and back.

For this I'm using the open source JAVA tool `ExiProcessor`, which is a executable JAR file and which makes this process very easy. Since I want to use it with `C#`, I need to exchange data between those two.

The easiest way is to write the XML data from C# to a file, read this file with `ExiProcessor` and then the other way round. But this isn't really fast.

Therefore I wonder what alternatives are there. I read that as of .NET Framework 4 you can use `MemoryMappedFiles`. I had a look, but it seems they only work between two applications that are using .NET Framework 4?

**Is there any other way to speed up the process?**

As a fallback I could use the JAVA sources and write my own application, but I would prefer to use the `ExiProcessor` as is.

Answer (score 1):

For mixed environments like this, [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org) is usually a good choice. Thrift is designed for lightweight, fast and easy to use RPC (and IPC) solutions. Amongst others, it supports both Java and C#. Might be worth a look.

If you want to stick with MMFs, this is also possible by just using the serialization part of Thrift and read/write date into/from a buffer or stream. You don't have to use the RPC stuff.

Have a lok at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653240/what-is-rpc-framework-and-apache-thrift/20664706#20664706) for a more exhaustive overview and a few links to other resources that help you getting started quickly.

Comment: But this solution would require to modify the executable ExiProcessor JAR, correct? Since I not only need to implement something on C# side, but also add the corresponding counterpart on Java? This is what I would like to avoid, since I don't have much experience with Java.

Comment: True. I didn't read "*I would prefer to use the ExiProcessor as is*" this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure , but if you are looking a way to use the jar,

You can try to convert the jar

http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/tutorial.html

or you can use a bridge like

http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/

hope this helps !!

Comment: Doesn't help much, since ExiProcessor is no library, but an executable JAR. Therefore I cannot just convert it to C# and then execute it there in my code, can I?