# Use the same Apache Thrift server in two different languages

Tags: javascript, java, server, thrift

It's possible to use the same Apache Thrift server for Javascript web and for Java? At the moment, I have a ThreadPoolServer for Javascript:

```
 TServer server = new TThreadPoolServer(new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
```

And a simple server for Java:

```
TServer jserver = new TSimpleServer(new Args(jserverTransport).processor(jprocessor));
```

Both of them share the same info. Now, I have this problem where somethimes the data comes incomplete in one of the clients and dont know if it's for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is, whether or not a particular service could be connected by a client in any arbitrary, Thrift-supported language, then the answer is a big **YES** because [that's what Thrift is all about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653240/what-is-rpc-framework-and-apache-thrift).

> Now, i have this problem where somethimes the data comes incomplete in one of the clients and dont know if it's for that.

Please [add the relevant information](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html), such as

1. what client language,
2. the Thrift protocol/transport setup
3. relevant parts of the code, and last not least
4. what error did you get (stacktrace included, if any)

> I forgot to say that im using an Http Server to connect to JavasScript. http://codeshare.io/llR5F 
>   Im not sure how to use it with the java client

The [Java HTP client](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/THttpClient.java) should work very similar to the JavaScript client. The Thrift library as a whole is very consistent across languages re how things work and how they are named.

Comment: I forgot to say that im using an Http Server to connect to JavasScript. https://codeshare.io/llR5F Im not sure how to use it with the java client

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Regards